# How to serialize both the elements and text in one tag?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have some xml code like:

```
<source-text>
<hlword>а</hlword>
п
<hlword>и</hlword>
чатка
</source-text>
```

As you can see, here I have some xml elements and some texts inside <source-text> tag. The order and the count of elements and text can vary..

How to write a class in c#, that can be serialized with XmlSerializer to this xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution (in VB):

Class:

```
Public Class source_text
    Sub New()
        items = New List(Of Object)
    End Sub
    <XmlText(GetType(String))>
    <XmlAnyElement>
    Public Property items As List(Of Object)
End Class
```

Code:

```
Function CreateElement(name As String, value As String)
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    Dim elem As XmlElement
    elem = doc.CreateElement(name)
    elem.InnerText = value
    Return elem
End Function

Sub New()
    source_text = New source_text
    source_text.items.Add("опе")
    source_text.items.Add(CreateElement("hlword", "ч"))
    source_text.items.Add("ат")
    source_text.items.Add(CreateElement("hlword", "ка"))
End Sub
```